# Facebook PHP SDK -> getting user id by email no longer possible?

Tags: php, facebook

Previously it was possible to get the facebook user id associated to an email by polling the api:

```
$facebook->api('/search?q=' . $email . '&type=user');
```

or via url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mailbox@example.com&type=user
```

The last time it worked for me was october 28th. Now an empty result is returned. Searching by anything else still works.

Did anything in the API change or is facebook now blocking email searches? I'm using the latest (3.1.1) PHP SDK and OAuth 2.0;

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has confirmed this as a bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266

1 month and still no fix ...

@Mod: the same question was asked later here: [Facebook Graph API "search" by email suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595396/facebook-graph-api-search-by-email-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: Facebook seem to enable that feature back, but with new changes from July 10, 2013 search by email is not working. Does anyone know if that issue is back or Facebook decided to disable search by email?