# Facebook Graph API "search" by email suddenly stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an application that issue search requests (FB Graph API) using an email address as the main query parameter, so basically we are searching users by email (e.g. /search?q=email@dot.com&type=user). Everything was working perfect until yesterday when suddenly we started to get 0 results from that request. We are not aware if something has changed on the way the search API works, or if without previous notice that feature is not supported anymore. Does anybody else has had the same issue, or has any info about it?

Comment: Do you have token? `A user access token is required to request this resource.`

Comment: Yes, I do have an access token. Yesterday FB did a push to production, but on the changelog nothing related is mentioned :(

Comment: Facebook introduced this bug on December 21, 2012. They've confirmed this is a bug and are tracking it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook PHP SDK -> getting user id by email no longer possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591436/facebook-php-sdk-getting-user-id-by-email-no-longer-possible)

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266) and should now be resolved. Thanks.

Comment: With new changes from July 10, 2013 search by email is not working (you can either try this in Graph API Explorer or using your application after setting 'July 2013 Changes Compatible'). Does anyone know if that issue is back or Facebook decided to disable search by email?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was deprecated because of low utilization, and they have no current plans to re-enable it. Have a look

```
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/453298034751100/
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked thru Facebook's documentation and they don't have specified you can search by email address, only by name.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (see the searching section).

Where did you find in their documentation you can search by email address?  Can you send me a link?

I'm really thinking someone hacked into that feature and now Facebook considers it a security hole, and they plugged it.

Comment: I don't recall reading it at any documentation neither, it just happened to work :) We took a shot using an email address as the query parameter and it worked. Probably, as you say, they found that out and fixed it. Not cool.

Comment: Even I am having the same issue, the results were coming earlier for email ids but now its not working

Comment: Sandhurst, where in their documentation did they say you can search by email address.  If it does say that, then it's a bug or a documentation error.  Can you please provide a link?

Comment: I can confirm that searching by email was working fine for a while now. I dont remember if it was part of the documentation but i certainly found it somewhere (official or not official documentation)