# Search for FB User ID from an Email ID - like in MS Outlook 2010 Social Connect Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-profile

Is there any method to search for FB User ID from email Address ?

Am developing a site where I would like to show the User Profile Pic based on his Email address - if the person is registered and the Profile Pic is made public.

Have tried searching - but am unable to get to any solution - where we can search for User ID - based on Email ID.

It is like how the Social Connect Plugin functions for Outlook 2010.

Thanx !

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595396/facebook-graph-api-search-by-email-suddenly-stopped-working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following graph API call:  `/search?q=email@dot.com&type=user`

However, it appears this functionality may have a bug in it.  See: [Facebook Graph API "search" by email suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595396/facebook-graph-api-search-by-email-suddenly-stopped-working)

The official bug is: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266

Answer (score 0):

The solution is bit tricky now, you can use the friends importer from a Google account, and populate your Google contact via the Google API !

I have setup a bot to to this automatically, but I cannot share it with you, sorry, you have to write ur own^^